# Regex repeated characters

Tags: php, regex

I have one regex to check if the 6 last numbers of a variable are not the same.
I don't understand why my regex is not working ?

If $tel = "0601244567" it's ok but if $tel = "0601555555" or anything with the last 6 characters it's not working.

```
if (!preg_match("/^0[1-79][0-9]{2}(?!(\d)\1{5}$)\d{6}$/i", $tel)) {
    $errors[] = array(
        "tel" => "Wrong phone number."
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this to your users... If they want to give you a phone number that ends in `444444`, you should just let them. Instead of rolling your own solution, why not just use one of the [*millions* of existing ones?](https://www.google.ca/search?q=phone+number+validation&oq=phone+number+validation&aqs=chrome..69i57.2861j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: My customer want this feature.

Comment: ahhhhh customers and their feature requests

Comment: Does your customer not understand that 455-5555 is a totally valid phone number? It's your job to talk them out of such idiotic requirements.

Comment: I think he knows valid phone numbers. He wants this feature, he paids for this feature, so i develop this feature. You don't know my customer and the nature of this developement, so i have a question i only want help about that and nothing else. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^(?!.*?(\d)\1{5}$)0[1-79]\d{8}$
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xN8nY6

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to keep the other rules i just want to disallow the last 6 caracters repeat

Comment: Sure you can keep them I mean instead of `\d+$` you can use `0[1-79][0-9]{8}$`

Comment: maybe because $tel variable is a string ?

Comment: No no this is PHP so that is not a problem. I just want to know for which tel number this regex didn't work. May be you can play with the link I provided and see which phone # is working for you.

Comment: the same if the link you provided.. 0601333333 !

Comment: In that link `0601333333` is not being matched (invalid). All matched inputs are colored and white lines are the one that are not matching (invalid input).

Comment: In my script : 0601333333 not matched, 0601333334 not matched.

Comment: See this link: http://regex101.com/r/aV2xW9 Here `0601333333` **not matched**, `0601333334` **matched** Both expected results as per the requirements. If you can post your code or reproduce the problem on ideone I will be able to quickly investigate & suggest.

Comment: `<?php
$tel = "0620111111";
if (!preg_match("/^(?!.*?(\d)\1{5})0[1-79]\d{8}$/i", $tel)) {
        echo "not valid";
    } else {
     echo "valid";
    }
echo "<hr />";
$tel2 = "0620111112";
if (!preg_match("/^(?!.*?(\d)\1{5})0[1-79]\d{8}$/i", $tel2)) {
        echo "not valid";
    } else {
     echo "valid";
    }

?>`

Comment: The first number must be not valid but it's valid !

Comment: `0620111111` is not valid as per: http://regex101.com/r/rA4wR7 but let me try your PHP code also locally.

Comment: See this **Online PHP Demo: http://ideone.com/vKxot9** You were missing `$` in the negative lookahead and more importantly use single quotes for regex